# The number of ways of having 3 aces of hearts among 5 ordered cards

Tags: combinatorics

My combinatorial reasoning will appreciate some help with this:

From a deck of $52$ cards John $5$ times does the following:

1. Picks one card from the deck.
2. He writes on a sheet of paper
       which card was drawn. He does so by ordering them. (That is, if the
       he picked 10 of heart, $5$ of spades, $3$ of clubs, ... in that order,
       then he writes $1º\  10$ of heart, $2º\ 5$ of spades and so on).
3. He put
       back the drawn card.

Question: In how many different way can 3 aces of hearts appear written on the paper?

**My attempt:**

Suppose John already wrote the numbers $1º,\ 2º,\ 3º,\ 4º$ and $5º$ on the paper. Then

1) There are  ${52 \choose 1}$ ways of picking one card from $52$.

2) John does that $5$ times.

3) Now place the 5 cards in some arbitrary order, say $AAANN$ (where $A$ denotes the aces of hearts and $N$ the no aces of hearts). Let ''put'' the places on them. This can be done in $5!$ (since, say, the 3rd place can only go to one card). Moreover, because the order among the $A$'s themselves doesn't matter and the same for the $N$'s we have $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$.

Then by the product rule we have

$$5{52 \choose 1} \frac{5!}{3!2!} = 2600\ \text{different ways.}$$

But the correct answer is $26010$ ]:. I'm way off it. I'v been thinking for a while but I don't know what combinations I haven't taken into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want exactly three aces of hearts, there are ${5 \choose 3}=10$ ways to choose where the aces appear.  Each of the other cards has $51$ choices, so the total is $10 \cdot 51^2=26010$

Answer (score 2):

$5\binom{52}{1}$ is **not** the count of picking any card five times.  $\binom{52}1^5$ is.

However, John does *not* do that.

He picks 3 ace-of-hearts and two other cards.  That's $\binom{51}2$ ways to pick 2 different cards, and $\binom{51}1$ ways to pick the same card twice.

Then arrange them.  $\binom{51}2\binom{5}{3,1,1}+\binom{51}{1}\binom{5}{3}=26010$

---

PS: $\binom{5}{3,1,1}=\frac{5!}{3!~1!~1!}$ is a multinomial coefficient.